# In database stored image getting disturb in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, image

I am working on a project which requires to stored the 32x32 size Icons(png) in table. I am storing the image in table, but when I am getting it to display on page it feels something distorted. These are the png images so somewhere it could be transparent. But when I am showing that image in list of asp.Net page the transparent spaces are filled with black color.

Are there any ways/methods to store the png image in the table without distorting it's quality.

Thanks

Comment: Before storing the PNG in the database, are you reading the image into a .NET class such as `Image` or `Bitmap` or are you just using a binary stream?

Comment: Yes, first it is converting into bitmap. I think, here I am doing the mistake. But what is the solution.

Comment: BMP *file format* does not support alpha transparency so yes that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you save Image to byte array with wrong ImageFormat. Use this code:

```
    public byte[] imageToByteArray(string imagePath)
    {
        return imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath));
    }


    public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            result = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return result;
    }
```